Determining voltage on branches with current sources in DC circuits using
I have a task on electric circuit theory where I need to find all currents flowing through the branches and corresponding voltages. To solve this problem, we need to use loop current method. The main problem is that I don't know what is the current sources J1,J2 and then how to determine voltages on branches with these sources.
The initial DC circuit:

Data of the circuit:

So, I made annotations with current and contours, where J1, J2 are fictitious co:

Then, I made the equations to calculate currents flowing in circuit and got the results which seems to be correct:

And my question is:

J1 and J2 are current sources in schematics. But what these current sources exactly are? For example, I can imagine that voltage sources E1 and E2 are just galvanic elements, but what about current sources - what are they?
So, for example, if these current sources are just elements on the circuit similar to EMF sources, I can determine the voltage just using second Kirchhoff's law? So,

P.s. maybe such description with a lot of images is too much, but I tried make my problem clearer.


J1 and J2 are current sources in schematics. But what these current sources exactly are?

This is a theoretical question, so it just doesn't matter. You have to treat them as mathematical entities that simply have the ability to produce a fixed current regardless of the voltage across them.
Real world devices that might be modeled as current sources include the collector-emitter branch of a BJT, a photodiode with a light shining on it, or a whole subcircuit of some kind. But which of those is being represented in this problem has no effect on the answer.

if these current sources are just elements on the circuit similar to EMF sources, I can determine the voltage just using second Kirchhoff's law?

Yes, you can use Kirchhoff's laws along with Ohm's law to form a system of equations that describes this circuit, and solve that system to find the voltages across the current sources. That is exactly what you are expected to do here.
